# how to capture the updates happening on dimension table

Tags: data-warehouse

i have a fact table joined to 5 dimension tables. both the fact and dimension tables have metadata fields DWcreateddate,DWupdatedate,DWdeleteddate,DWdeletedflag.am building a table which flattens out the fact table by joining all the dimension on surrogate keys.

am doing the incremental load to the flattened table.am tracking the upserts happening on the fact table by metadata fields and doing the incremental load(stored procedure does that)...if a record is updated to a new name in the dimension table the fact DWupdated date doesnt have the latest date..so my flattened table is ending up having the old name..can some one help how to overcome this

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. This will help getting useful answers. 

I flagged this question for closing.

Answer (score 2):

You should never update your dimension.  Once created, should be left alone with a few exceptions like slowly changing dimensions.  You should be creating a new dimension record instead.